# Angular Testing with Karma Jasmine Failed

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test an Angular Component with Karma Jasmine for the very first time.

My `index.html` looks like :

```
<body ng-app="heroApp">
  <!-- components match only elements -->
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Hero</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And `index.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
        this.hero = {
            name: 'Miles Bronson'
        };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

And the **component** `heroDetail.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular){
    'use strict';

    function HeroDetailController(){

    }

    angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail',{
        template:'<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>',
        controller:HeroDetailController,
        bindings:{
            hero: '='
        }
    });

})(window.angular);
```

Now my karma spec file looks like :

```
describe('Component:heroDetailComponent',function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('heroApp');
    });

    var element,
        scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile){
        scope = $rootScope;
        scope.name = "Miles Bronson";
        element = angular.element('<hero-detail hero="name"></hero-detail>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should render the text',function(){
        var span = element.find('span');
        expect(span.text()).toBe('Name: Miles Bronson')
    });

});
```

But this **failed**. `Saying :`

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) Component:heroDetailComponent should render the text FAILED
        Expected 'Name: ' to be 'Name: Miles Bronson'.
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:35:29)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.065 secs / 0.058 secs)
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**  Please help. I also tried with `element.isolateScope().name` **but that rendered undefined.**.

Which is the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: I think `{{$ctrl.hero.name}}` in template should be `{{hero.name}}` and that will work fine.

Comment: @AdnanUmer .. But this is controllerAs syntax right ?

Comment: there is no equivalent of ControllerAs in angular 2

Comment: @AdnanUmer Sorry for not pointing this out. I am in Angular 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `scope = $rootScope;` should be `scope = $rootScope.$new();`

UPD: You also had a mistake in your setup: `scope.name = "Miles Bronson";` should be `scope.hero = { name: "Miles Bronson" };`

I was able to make this test pass in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/9ZLzr4AWtCB0q43vBAdf?p=preview

Working test:

```
describe('Component:heroDetailComponent', function() {
  var element,
        scope;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.hero = { name: "Miles Bronson" };
        element = angular.element('<hero-detail hero="hero"></hero-detail>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should render the text',function(){
        var span = element.find('span');
        expect(span.text()).toBe('Name: Miles Bronson')
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the plunker.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder added

Comment: Oh okay . My bad . I was passing `hero="hero.name"` . Such a silly mistake. Thanks for your time and pointing that out .

Comment: I am gettinga  new error. Please see the question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763818/angular-directive-isolate-scope-unit-test-failed