# Angular Directive Isolate Scope Unit Test Failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test an Angular Component with Karma Jasmine for the very first time.

My `index.html` looks like :

```
<body ng-app="heroApp">
  <!-- components match only elements -->
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Hero</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And `index.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
        this.hero = {
            name: 'Miles Bronson'
        };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

And the **component** `heroDetail.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular){
    'use strict';

    function HeroDetailController(){

    }

    angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail',{
        template:'<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>',
        controller:HeroDetailController,
        bindings:{
            hero: '='
        }
    });

})(window.angular);
```

Now my karma spec file looks like :

```
describe('Component:heroDetailComponent',function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('heroApp');
    });

    var element,
        scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.hero = {
            name:'Miles Bronson'
        };
        element = angular.element('<hero-detail hero="hero"></hero-detail>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should render the text',function(){
        expect(element.isolateScope().hero.name).toBe('Miles Bronson');

    });

});
```

But this **failed**. `Saying :`

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) Component:heroDetailComponent should render the text FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:38:43)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.047Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.763 secs / 0.047 secs)
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**  Please help.

**UPDATE**

`Though this works` :

```
it('should render the text',function(){
    var span = element.find('span');
    expect(span.text()).toBe('Name: Miles Bronson');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing controller reference. It should be:

```
element.isolateScope().$ctrl.hero.name
```

See updated plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9ZLzr4AWtCB0q43vBAdf

Comment: Savior. You are the man. But just a stupid question. In the describe block there is no reference of `$ctrl`. So where does it get the reference to work with ? Should not it just work with `hero.name` because that's the only thing in that block?

Comment: well, I guess it would if your `hero-detail` would be a pure directive, but it is a component with controller. So it looks logical that data is stored in controller namespace. But I do not have much experience with angular components, so I can't really tell how do they work in depth